# Aplicación en Delphi se cuelga cuando incorpora una DLL

Tags: delphi-2010

Tengo creada una dll sencilla en Delphi 2010. Al intentar usarla en otra aplicación, funciona correctamente pero, cuando cierro la aplicación, no queda cerrada completamente. El proceso aparentemente desaparece, pero en la pestaña "Usuarios" del administrador de tareas aún aparece para matar el programa (solo en ese caso se cierra completamente).

Si lo hago en depuración, al cerrar se puede ver cómo el depurador sigue esperando a la finalización para volver al modo de diseño.

La DLL "ejemplo.dll" la estoy usando de la siguiente forma:

```
function InicializarDLL() : Integer; stdcall; external 'ejemplo.dll';
```

Esto lo introduzco junto al resto de procedimientos de la aplicación.

El código en que se llama la función es el siguiente:

```
procedure Tmenuenvasado.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  Showmessage(Inttostr(InicializarDLL));

end;
```

En este caso estoy devolviendo y sacando por pantalla el número de elementos que inicializa el DLL (lo que hace es rellenar una TList interna con valores predeterminados) y eso me lo muestra correctamente.

El bloqueo de la aplicación se produce al cerrar la aplicación, se haya pulsado el botón o no se haya pulsado (es decir, ocurre siempre).

¿Alguna idea de qué puede fallar?

Gracias

Añado:  He editado la dll simplificándola hasta el punto de solo devolver un número fijo, y sigue dándome el mismo problema:

```
library ejemplo;

uses
  ShareMem,
  SysUtils,
  Generics.Collections,
  Classes;

function InicializarDLL() : Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;

exports InicializarDLL;

begin

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Habría que ver el proyecto completo para ver si hay algún otro detalle que te hayas olvidado. A priori lo que has puesto no parece tener problemas.
Revisa:

- Que en la implementación no hayas olvidado añadir `stdcall`
- Revisa la llamada a `ShareMem`

Das pocos datos para saber qué puede estar pasando...

Comment: Me faltaba el stdcall en la implementación, pero aún poniéndola no funciona. He editado la pregunta inicial para añadir el código de la dll.

Comment: Bueno, pues he comprobado que el fallo me lo provocaba el hecho de incluir el ShareMem en las unidades.

Lo que he hecho es quitarlo y en una función que uso strings como parámetros, utilizaré PChar en su lugar (esta función estaba comentada cuando he hecho las pruebas, para que no influyera); aunque me queda la duda de por qué se produce.

Comment: @davidrgh En tu ejemplo usabas un parámetro de tipo integer, de ahí que no habíam comentado nada. Si programas DLL's es "recomendable" utilizar tipos nativos de windows en lugar de los específicos de Delphi. en este caso, en lugar de string, deberías usar PChar como has comentado. En lugar de tipos fichero, deberías utilizar Handles,....

Comment: Claro, es que puse este ejemplo sin darme cuenta de que tenía las otras funciones también programadas (aunque no se declararan en el programa anfitrión) y eso era lo que me estaba trayendo de cabeza.

Lo tengo ahora con PChar las cadenas que tengo que usar y va de lujo.